# Using a regular expression in VIM, how do I replace the asterisks of an unordered list with numbers?

Tags: regex, vim

Using a regular expression in a single substitution in VIM, how do I change:

```
*  item 1
*  item 2
*  item 3
```

to

```
1. item 1
2. item 2
3. item 3
```